# org.ksoap2.transport.HttpResponseException 400 bad request error when calling .svc from Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, wcf, ksoap2

I've seen other posts on this, but none seem to help. The issue seems to be adding the parameter to the request.  Note this is a .svc -- not wsdl.  The C# .svc file has a data contract of:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyMethod_In
{
    [DataMember]
    public string rc;
}
```

Kotlin code: (constants take out for easier reading, and names changed to protect the innocent)

```
    val soapObject = SoapObject("https://qa.mysite.com/ws/MyService.svc/", "MyMethod")
    soapObject.addProperty("rc", "xyz")
    val envelope = SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11)
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject)
    envelope.dotNet = true
    val httpTransport = HttpTransportSE("https://qa.mysite.com/ws/MyService.svc/MyMethod")

try {
    httpTransport.call("https://qa.mysite.com/ws/MyService.svc/MyMethod", envelope)
    blah blah
}
    catch (e: Exception) {
    exception happens with 400 error
}
```

The problem seems to be the `soapObject.addProperty` line.  I've also tried other code where I construct the property info and set the name, type, and value, but I still always get the 400 error.  I tried that with a type of String and a type of JSON, and it made no difference.

I'm not totally sure of some of the hard coded values, but I seem to be calling the service correctly, because I tried another service with no input parameters, and this worked fine and got the response.

I'm probably missing one small thing, but can't find it.  Any ideas on why the bad request?  Thanks

Comment: Can you successfully call this WCF service if you use C#?

Comment: Yes.  And I've also been experimenting with okhttp3 4.2.0.  Same deal -- bad request.  That code seems easier too -- makeRequest which creates an okHttpClient, creates a request (and adds the parameter), and parses the response.  I do a .post so I won't get a 405.  Looked good, but I still get a 400.  It looks similar to the server log where the C# one is called correctly.  Will have to do some more debugging.

Comment: Need to JSON stringify in Kotlin somehow? I suspect my issue may have to do with the C# service having: 

[OperationContract, WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for okhttp3, version 4.2.0.  As I suspected, I need to pass JSON data.  This code does it:

```
val json = "{ \"rc\":\"xyz\" }"
val mediaTypeJson = "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaType()
val requestBody = json.toString().toRequestBody(mediaTypeJson)

val request = Request.Builder()
    .url("https://qa.mysite.com/ws/MyService.svc/MyMethod")
    .post(requestBody)
    .build()
```

Should probably clean it up and use gson or something, but at least this works.